# How to get nodes that have a given amount of outgoing relationships with a given property in Neo4j Cypher?

Tags: nosql, neo4j, graph-databases, cypher

In my domain a node can have several relationships of the same type to other entities. Each relationship have several properties and I'd like to retrieve the nodes that are connected by at least 2 relationships that present a given property.

EG: A relationship between nodes have a property `year`. How do I find the nodes that have at least two outgoing relationships with the `year` set to `2012`?

Why `Chypher` query so far looks like this (syntax error)

```
START x = node(*)
MATCH x-[r:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->y
WITH COUNT(r.year == 2012) AS years
WHERE HAS(r.year) AND years > 1
RETURN x;
```

I tried also nesting queries but I believe that it's not allowed in `Cypher`. The closest thing is the following but I do not know how to get rid of the nodes with value 1:

```
START n = node(*)
MATCH n-[r:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->c
WHERE HAS(r.year) AND r.year == 2012
RETURN n, COUNT(r) AS counter
ORDER BY counter DESC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query

```
START n = node(*)
MATCH n-[r:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->c
WHERE HAS(r.year) AND r.year=2012
WITH n, COUNT(r) AS rc
WHERE rc > 1
RETURN n, rc
```

Comment: i'm curious whether the `r.year` part is powered by index? either way, isn't this faster? `START r = relationship:yearIndex('year:2012')
MATCH n-[r:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->c
WITH n, COUNT(r) AS rc
WHERE rc > 1
RETURN n, rc`

Comment: @ulkas it isn't, but they don't mention an index in the question. You should definitely avoid node(*) and use indexes in start lookups when possible. :)