# Return if no relationship with a given property exists?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I found this question about checking that [no outgoing relationships of a given label exist on a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952332/return-node-if-relationship-is-not-present), and [this one for checking the count of outgoing relationships with a given property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751183/how-to-get-nodes-that-have-a-given-amount-of-outgoing-relationships-with-a-given), but what I need to do is get the nodes which *don't* have a relationship for which a given property is set. I'm sure I'm making this more difficult for myself!

What I have so far is this:

```
MATCH (n:Node)-[r:WEIGHTING]->()
WHERE NOT(ANY(rel IN r WHERE EXISTS(r.PROP)))
RETURN z
```

But, obviously, the `r` at this point is a single relationship, not the collection of relationships. I *think* I need to get a `WITH` clause involved, but I'm very much out of my depth!

How would I go about getting the set of `Node`s which have no outgoing `WEIGHTING` relationships that have a `PROP` property?

I hope that's enough detail - sorry if it's unclear!

Thanks very much,
Tom

Comment: Should this also return nodes that don't have any outgoing WEIGHTING relationships at all, or do you only want those with WEIGHTING relationships, but none which have the PROP property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this :

```
MATCH (n:Node)-[r:WEIGHTING]->()
WITH n, collect(r.PROP) AS props
WHERE size(props) = 0
RETURN n
```

Or :

```
MATCH (n:Node)-[r:WEIGHTING]->()
WITH n, collect(r) AS rs
WHERE NONE ( x IN rs WHERE EXISTS(x.PROP) )
RETURN n
```

Comment: Perfect! Every time I post on SO, I learn about a brand new function in Cypher. `collect` is exactly what I needed - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With Neo4j there tend to be several ways to do what you need. One alternate query could be:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
// only need the next WHERE clause if a WEIGHTING relationship is required
WHERE SIZE((n)-[:WEIGHTING]->()) > 0
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:WEIGHTING]->()
WHERE EXISTS (r.PROP)
WITH n 
WHERE r is null
RETURN n
```